# MongoDB launching on restart?

Tags: mongodb

I just installed mongodb on my cloud machine following instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

One of the problems I am facing is that, on restart of machine, mongodb is getting launched. I want to disable that operations, I want to launch mongodb manually.

I read that I have to modify /etc/init/mongod.conf file to achieve that, but I am not sure what I have to change. Could somebody please point out what I have to do?

Comment: Off-topic for StackOverflow since this is a server adminstraition issue. Since it's ubuntu then it would be better on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com), but actually already answered of course [How to enable or disable services?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Answer (score 0):

No, the mongod is being started by the /etc/init.d/mongod script.

This is a standard *nix convention for Debian and Redhat amongst other distros.

There are a number of /etc/ directories named to indicate which run level they correspond to.  As *nix boots up it changes the run level and will either start or stop processes using the scripts in the /etc/rc#.d directory.

There are some helper scripts that essentially create or remove symlinks from the /etc/init.d directory script to rc#.d directories.

This is talked about in detail here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106656/how-do-services-in-debian-work-and-how-can-i-manage-them

Needless to say this is not a programming question, but rather a system administration question better suited for the unix board or serveradmin.